# Filter sequences with more than 8 same consecutive nucleotides in a fastq file?

Tags: bioinformatics, fastq

I want to filter my sequences which has more than 8 same consecutive nucleotides like `"GGGGGGGG"`, `"CCCCCCCC"`, etc in my *fastq* files.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. The quick and incorrect way, which might be close enough: `grep -E -B1 -A2 'A{8}|C{8}|G{8}|T{8}' yourfile.fastq`.
   This will miss blocks where the 8-mer is split across two lines (e.g. the first line ends with AAAA and the second starts with AAAA). It also assumes the output has blocks of 4 lines each.
2. The proper way: write a little program (in Python, or a language of your choice) which buffers one FASTQ block (e.g. 4 lines) and checks that the concatenation of the previous (buffered) block's sequence and the current block's sequence do not have an 8-mer as above. If that's the case, then output the buffered block.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up to use below codes in R and solved my problem.

```
library(ShortRead)

fq <- FastqFile("/Users/path/to/file")
reads_fq <- readFastq(fq)


trimmed_fq <- reads_fq[grep("GGGGGGGG|TTTTTTTTT|AAAAAAAAA|CCCCCCCCC", 
                       sread(reads_fq), invert = TRUE)]

writeFastq(trimmed_fq, "new_name_for_fq.fastq", compress = FALSE)
```

Comment: Please accept as answer if this resolves the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python package *biotite* for it (https://www.biotite-python.org).

Let's say you have the following FASTQ file:

```
@Read:01
CCCAAGGGCCCCCCCCCACTGCGATCACCTGGTTGCTGCCGGGAAAGGAGACCCAGGAGGTGAAACGGACTGGTGAATTG
CGGGGGTAGATATGGCGGGTGACACAAAAACATATAATCGGGCC
+
.+.+:'-FEAC-4'4CA-3-5#/4+?*G@?,<)<E&5(*82C9FH4G315F*DF8-4%F"9?H5535F7%?7@+6!FDC&
+4=4+,@2A)8!1B#,HA18)1*D1A-.HGAED%?-G10'6>:2
@Read:02
AACACTACTTCGCTGTCGCCAAAGGTTGGTGTAGGTCGGACTTCGAATTATCGATACTAGTTAGTAGTACGTCGCGTGGC
GTCAGCTCGTATGCTCTCAGAACAGGGAGAACTAGCACCGTAAGTAACCTAGCTCCCAAC
+
6%9,@'4A0&%.19,1E)E?!9/$.#?(!H2?+E"")?6:=F&FE91-*&',,;;$&?@2A"F.$1)%'"CB?5$<.F/$
7055E>#+/650B6H<8+A%$!A=0>?'@",8:#5%18&+3>'8:28+:5F0);E9<=,+
```

This is a script, that should do the work:

```py
import biotite.sequence.io.fastq as fastq
import biotite.sequence as seq


# 'GGGGGGGG', 'CCCCCCCC', etc.
consecutive_nucs = [seq.NucleotideSequence(nuc * 8) for nuc in "ACGT"]

fastq_file = fastq.FastqFile("Sanger")
fastq_file.read("example.fastq")
# Iterate over sequence entries in file
for header in fastq_file:
    sequence = fastq_file.get_sequence(header)
    # Iterative over each of the consecutive sequences
    for consecutive_nuc in consecutive_nucs:
        # Find all indices, where a match was found
        matches = seq.find_subsequence(sequence, consecutive_nuc)
        if len(matches) > 0:
            # If any match was found report it
            print(
                f"Found '{consecutive_nuc}' "
                f"in sequence '{header}' at position {matches[0]}"
            )
```

This is the output:

```
Found 'CCCCCCCC' in sequence 'Read:01' at pos 8
```